# Cyclomatic complexity when if conditions are combined

Tags: java, c#, c, visual-studio, static-code-analysis

I would like to compute the cyclomatic complexity of below code.

```
    int test(int a, int b)
    {
          int result = 0;
          if (a == 0 && b == 0)
              result = -1;
          else
              result = a * b;

          return result;
    }
```

Mathwork's Polyspace tool calculates a value of 2.
Visual studio and Metrics plugin for Eclipse shows 3. Which is correct?

Comment: The answer is 2, as an example like this can be seen in wikipedia: "*If the code had one single-condition IF statement, there would be two paths through the code: one where the IF statement evaluates to TRUE and another one where it evaluates to FALSE, so the complexity would be 2*"

Comment: I wonder what do eclipse and visual studio report if instead of filling the variable `result`, you would type `return -1` and `return a*b`

Comment: @AnderBiguri When I use `return -1` and `return a*b`, both VS and Eclipse shows the same value '3'. However if I change the line 4 to `if (a == 0)` they shows '2'.

Comment: Any explanation why Visual Studio and Eclipse reports '3'?

Answer (score 3):

You have 3 paths through the program because "&&" is a short-cut condition.
The 3 paths/tests are:

```
    a=1 and b=7 (actually anything)  which short cuts and returns a*b or 7
    a=0 and b=7  which goes to else and returns a*b or 0
    a=0 and b=0  which goes to then and returns -1'
```

The fact that b is not evaluated in the first condition can be significant.

Answer (score 2):

> Cyclomatic complexity
>   is a software metric that provides a quantitative measure of the
>   logical complexity of a program. When used in the context of the basis path testing
>   method, the value computed for cyclomatic complexity defines the number of inde-
>   pendent paths in the basis set of a program and provides us with an upper bound for
>   the number of tests that must be conducted to ensure that all statements have been
>   executed at least once.

An 
independent path
is any path through the program that introduces at least one
new set of processing statements or a new condition.

There are only 2 independent paths in your code, one that goes through if branch and one through else branch.